# Authenticated requests after sign in with React Query and NextAuth

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-query, next-auth

I'm having troubled sending an authenticated request to my API immediately after signing in to my Nextjs app using NextAuth. The request that is sent after signing in returns data for and unauthenticated user.

I believe the issue is that React Query is using a previous version of the query function with an undefined jwt (which means its unauthenticated). It makes sense because the query key is not changing so React Query does not think it's a new query, but, I was under the impression that signing in would cause `loading` to be set to true temporarily then back to false, which would cause React Query to send a fresh request.

I've tried invalidating all the queries in the app using queryClient, but that did not work. I've also used React Query Devtools to invalidate this specific query after signing in but it still returns the unauthenticated request. Only after refreshing the page does it actually send the authenticated request.

```js
// useGetHome.js
const useGetHome = () => {
  const [session, loading] = useSession();
  console.log(`session?.jwt: ${session?.jwt}`);
  return useQuery(
    'home',
    () => fetcher(`/home`, session?.jwt),
    {
      enabled: !loading,
    },
  );
}

// fetcher
const fetcher = (url, token) => {
  console.log(`token: ${token}`);  
  let opts = {};
  if (token) {
    opts = {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      },
    };
  }

  const res = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_URL}${url}`, opts);

  if (!res.ok) {
    const error = await res.json();
    throw new Error(error.message);
  }

  return res.json();
}

// Home.js
const Home = () => {
  const { data: home_data, isLoading, error } = useGetHome();
  ...

  return(
    ...
  )
}
```

Attached is the console immediately after signing in. You can see the the session object contains the jwt after signing in, but in the fetcher function it is undefined.

[console after signing in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UG7Gq.png)

Any help here is appreciated. Is there a better way to handle authenticated requests using React Query and NextAuth? Thank you!

Comment: it seems like you have set up the dependent query correctly. if `useSession` is triggering a re-render when the token arrives, I would expect the `enabled` flag to turn on the query once you have a token, and thus triggering a fetch with the token. Looking at the log statement just now - where is the `token` coming from that you are logging? I only see `url` and `opts` being passed to the `fetcher` ...

Comment: Oh good catch that's actually a typo. I cleaned up the code a bit for the purpose of posting here. Fixed it.

Comment: Your code looks fine imo. Can you put it in a codesandbox?

Comment: Codepen here: https://codesandbox.io/s/dry-https-f44y3?file=/pages/index.js

As I put this together I realized what was causing the issue. In my next-auth signIn method I had it set to `redirect: false`. Because of that, React Query was not refetching after sign in. You can see that in the code pen. I'm still curious tho if there's a smarter way to go about this entire process.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried a similar situation here and struggled the same thing but the enabled property worked fine for me and it is good to go right now.

https://github.com/maxtsh/music

Just check my repo to see how it works, that might help.